# Get the URI for an API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have created an API for showing data with DataTables. I have a common view and the only thing is changing is the URL where the DataTables reads the data. For that, I have a model

```
var model = new TableUI()
{
    ApiUrl = "/api/TableAzureCategory/Search",
    Fields = new FieldUI[] {
        new FieldUI() { Label = "ID", Data = "ID" },
        new FieldUI() { Label = "Category", Data = "Name" }
    }
};
```

The variable `ApiUrl` has the URI. This is a text and I don't like it. Is there a way to give the URI\URL for a WebApi? For example, I'm looking for a function that receives the controller name and the method I want to use and it returns an url.

I saw [Hyprlinkr](https://github.com/ploeh/Hyprlinkr) on GitHub but it doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: Do you mean you want to set ApiUrl like "https://localhost:xxx/api/TableAzureCategory/Search"?If so you can use `HttpContext.Request.Host.Value` to get localhost:xxx.And use `HttpContext.Request.Path` get path.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know the API url, is there a way to give it based on controller and action?

Comment: `HttpContext.Request.Path` can get current route,for example,if you are in TestController,Test Action,you will get `/Test/Test`.

Comment: I know but I want a function that gives me url based on controller and action. For example, `var lnk = fnz.GetApiLink("Search", "TableAzureCategory")` so the result is `lnk = "/api/TableAzureCategory/Search"`